# Get binomial coefficients

Tags: matlab, binomial-coefficients

In an attempt to vectorize a particular piece of Matlab code, I could not find a straightforward function to generate a list of the binomial coefficients. The best I could find was `nchoosek`, but for some inexplicable reason this function only accepts integers (not vectors of integers).  My current solution looks like this:

```
mybinom = @(n) arrayfun(@nchoosek, n*ones(1,n), 1:n)
```

This generates the set of binomial coefficients for a given value of `n`. However, since the binomial coefficients are always symmetric, I know that I am doing twice as much work as necessary.  I'm sure that I could create a solution that exploits the symmetry, but I'm sure that it would be at the expense of readability.

Is there a more elegant solution than this, perhaps using a Matlab function that I am not aware of?  Note that I am not interested in using the symbolic toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to minimize operations you can go along these lines:

```
n = 6;

k = 1:n;
result = [1 cumprod((n-k+1)./k)]

>> result

result =

     1     6    15    20    15     6     1
```

This requires very few operations per coefficient, because each cofficient is obtained exploiting the previously computed one.

You can reduce the number of operations by approximately half if you take into account the symmetry:

```
m1 = floor(n/2);
m2 = ceil(n/2);
k = 1:m2;
result = [1 cumprod((n-k+1)./k)];
result(n+1:-1:m1+2) = result(1:m2);
```

Comment: Will this be numerically stable for larger `n`? In other words, do you have any idea when I might start getting non-integer values coming out of this?

Comment: @nispio I would say very stable, because it doesn't compute factorials and then divide them. So at least it avoids overflows. The largest number involved in the computation is the binomial coefficient itself. However, for n as low as 50 it does give small errors. Anyway, since the errors are much smaller than 1, why not just do `result = round(result)` at the end?

Answer (score 2):

What about a modified version of Luis Mendo's solution - but **in logarithms**:

```
n = 1e4;
m1 = floor(n/2);
m2 = ceil(n/2);
k = 1:m2;

% Attempt to compute real value
out0 = [1 cumprod((n-k+1)./k)];
out0(n+1:-1:m1+2) = out0(1:m2);

% In logarithms
out1 = [0 cumsum((log(n-k+1)) - log(k))];
out1(n+1:-1:m1+2) = out1(1:m2);

plot(log(out0) - out1, 'o-')
```

The advantage of working with logarithms is that you can set `n = 1e4;` and still obtain a good approximation of the real value (`nchoosek(1e4, 5e3)` returns `Inf` and this is **not** a good approximation at all!).

**EDIT following horchler's comment**

You can use the `gammaln` function to obtain the same result but it's not faster. The two approximations seem to be quite different:

```
n = 1e7;
m1 = floor(n/2);
m2 = ceil(n/2);
k = 1:m2;

% In logarithms
tic
out1 = [0 cumsum((log(n-k+1)) - log(k))];
out1(n+1:-1:m1+2) = out1(1:m2);
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.912649 seconds.

tic
k = 0:m2;
out2 = gammaln(n + 1) - gammaln(k + 1) - gammaln(n - k + 1);
out2(n+1:-1:m1+2) = out2(1:m2);
toc
% Elapsed time is 1.020188 seconds.

tmp = out2 - out1;
plot(tmp, '.')

prctile(tmp, [0 2.5 25 50 75 97.5 100])
%   1.0e-006 *
%    -0.2217   -0.1462   -0.0373    0.0363    0.1225    0.2943    0.3846
```

Is adding three `gammaln` worse than adding `n` logarithms? Or viceversa?

Comment: Very nice. I like this. A version of this in terms of [`gammaln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html) is given at the end of [this section on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficient_in_programming_languages). As that's a compiled function it'd be interesting to see which was faster and/or more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Octave only

<del>You can use bincoeff function.


Example: `bincoeff(5, 0:5)`</del>

**EDIT :**
Only improvement I can think of goes like this. Maybe you already thought this trivial solution and didn't like it.

```
# Calculate only the first half
mybinomhalf = @(n) arrayfun(@nchoosek, n*ones(1,n/2+1), 0:n/2)

# pad your array symmetrically
mybinom = @(n) padarray(mybinomhalf(n), [0 n/2], 'symmetric', 'post')

# I couldn't test it and this line may not work
```

Comment: `bincoeff` is not found in my Matlab installation, and I have pretty much every toolbox.  Are you sure this is not a custom script or an Octave function?

Comment: Ah sorry, it must be an octave specific function then, looking at Matlab references I found this. http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/binomial.html Example 1 in the link would work for you I suppose

Comment: The binomial function in that link is part of the symbolic toolbox, which I am intentionally avoiding as mentioned in the post.  Thanks, though.